# NuGet - Reinstalling packages doesn't update the HintPath

Tags: nuget

I had a package repository (cache) set to some place on disk, centrally, using the `repositoryPath` NuGet.config setting.

Then I changed my mind about using that, since the path gets added to the `HintPath` in the proj file uses a relative path that won't work on colleagues' machines.

Trouble is, now the `HintPath`s need fixing to `..\packages\etc` so I thought I'd just run `Update-Package Whatever -Reinstall` with the package source in the Package Manage Console set to our TeamCity feed.

That reinstalls them all, sure, but the `HintPath`s didn't get updated!

Why not?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It did.

I just hadn't saved all! So the diff tool didn't see any changes.

Comment: You saved me :)